# Sum Values from column where second column is distinct?

Tags: c#, sql, excel

### Back Story

---

I am working on a Form for our Engineer that is meant to "automate" our Bill of Material generation. We have a program called AutoAttibute (by Cadig) used with AutoCAD that gets the values for each selected "Block" and outputs it to an excel file. There is no option to output it to any other format (SQL, Access, etc.).

The basic layout for the table that is generated by AutoAttribute is as follows:

```
 Material | Total Length Weight 
--------------------------------
 name1    | 34        
 name1    | 34        
 name2    | 34        
 name2    | 34        
 name3    | 34        
 name3    | 34 
 name4    | 33        
 name4    | 33        
 name5    | 1254
 name6    | 324
```

There are other columns generated but these are the ones I need to focus on.

Once this file is made, we had been using MS Access to get the sums of the values in the 2nd column.

**Here was the query:**

I don't have the exact query we used, but basically it was:

```
Select Distinct [Material], 
 [Total Length Weight] 
from `table` 
where [Material] <> ''
```

Which gave me:

```
 Material | Total Length Weight 
--------------------------------
 name1    | 34        
 name2    | 34        
 name3    | 34        
 name4    | 33        
 name5    | 1254
 name6    | 324
```

Then, in a separate Query:

```
Select Sum [Total Length Weight]
From Query 1
```

Which gave me:

```
 Sum([Total Length Weight])
----------------------------
 1713
```

Then we could use that value to do other things, like being used as a variable in another formula that showed the total weight for the project.

### New Issues

---

I am now creating a brand new form using C#, and I am having problems re-creating the queries.

I am using a connection string:

```
string file = "D:\\Cut-Lengths\\13-1311 CUT-LENGTHS.xlsx";
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
```

Then, I have the following queries:

```
string query = "Select Sum([CUT-LENGTH-WEIGHT]) AS [SumOfCUT-LENGTH-WEIGHT], Sum([TOTAL-SHEETING-WEIGHT]) AS [SumOfTOTAL-SHEETING-WEIGHT], Sum([TOTAL-ITEM-WEIGHT]) AS [SumOfTOTAL-ITEM-WEIGHT] From [Sheet1$]";

string query2 = "Select COUNT([Total-Length-Weight]) AS `Total Length Weight` From [Sheet1$]";

string query3 = "Select DISTINCT [Total-Length-Weight] AS `Total Length Weight`, [Material] AS `Material`, [Order] From [Sheet1$] WHERE [Material] <> '' ORDER BY [Order]";

string table = "Select * From [Sheet1$]";
```

I use these queries to fill 4 dataGridViews, as well as several TextBoxes on the form.

`query2` is very wrong, I know. That is where I am attempting to recreate the query from Access, but no matter what I try, I can't get it to work.

Other ways of the same query I have tried:

```
string query2 = "Select Sum(DISTINCT [Total-Length-Weight]) AS `Total Length Weight` From [Sheet1$]";

string query2 = "Select DISTINCT [material], Sum([Total-Length-Weight]) AS `Total Length Weight` From [Sheet1$]";
```

And there are others I can't remember at the moment. I know one of them involved a sub-query that never even loaded the form.

I really need help, and I just don't know what I am doing wrong.

### Full Form Code

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace excelConnectiontests
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SetFirstRowSelected()
        {
            if (gvExcelData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                var row = gvExcelData.Rows[0];
                var row2 = gvExcelData2.Rows[0];
                var row3 = gvExcelData3.Rows[0];
                var row4 = gvExcelData4.Rows[0];

                txtCutLengthWeight.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                txtTotalSheetingWeight.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                txtTotalItemWeight.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                //and so on

                int value1 = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
                int value2 = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value);
                int value3 = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value);
                int value4 = 0;
                if (txtCutSheetingWeight.Text != "")
                {
                    value4 = Convert.ToInt32(txtCutSheetingWeight.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    value4 = 0;
                }


                txtNetWeight.Text = (value1 + value2 + value3 + value4).ToString();

                gvExcelData.CurrentCell = row.Cells[0]; //set focus to first cell in first row
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string file = "D:\\Cut-Lengths\\13-1311 CUT-LENGTHS.xlsx";
            string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";

            string CutTubes = "";
            string CutSheeting = "";
            string UncutTubes = "";
            string UncutSheeting = "";
            string NonSteel = "";
            string p31 = "";

            string query = "Select Sum([CUT-LENGTH-WEIGHT]) AS [SumOfCUT-LENGTH-WEIGHT], Sum([TOTAL-SHEETING-WEIGHT]) AS [SumOfTOTAL-SHEETING-WEIGHT], Sum([TOTAL-ITEM-WEIGHT]) AS [SumOfTOTAL-ITEM-WEIGHT] From [Sheet1$]";
            string query2 = "Select COUNT([Total-Length-Weight]) AS `Total Length Weight` From [Sheet1$]";
            string query3 = "Select DISTINCT [Total-Length-Weight] AS `Total Length Weight`, [Material] AS `Material`, [Order] From [Sheet1$] WHERE [Material] <> '' ORDER BY [Order]";
            string table = "Select * From [Sheet1$]";

            OleDbConnection connObj = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            connObj.Open();

            // Uncut Steel
            OleDbCommand cmdObj4 = new OleDbCommand(query3, connObj);
            OleDbDataAdapter daObj4 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdObj4);
            DataTable dtObj4 = new DataTable();
            daObj4.Fill(dtObj4);
            gvExcelData4.DataSource = dtObj4;

            // Totals
            OleDbCommand cmdObj3 = new OleDbCommand(table, connObj);
            OleDbDataAdapter daObj3 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdObj3);
            DataTable dtObj3 = new DataTable();
            daObj3.Fill(dtObj3);
            gvExcelData3.DataSource = dtObj3;

            // Length Weight
            OleDbCommand cmdObj = new OleDbCommand(query, connObj);
            OleDbDataAdapter daObj = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdObj);
            DataTable dtObj = new DataTable();
            daObj.Fill(dtObj);
            gvExcelData.DataSource = dtObj;


            // Total Length Weight
            OleDbCommand cmdObj2 = new OleDbCommand(query2, connObj);
            OleDbDataAdapter daObj2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdObj2);
            DataTable dtObj2 = new DataTable();
            daObj2.Fill(dtObj2);
            gvExcelData2.DataSource = dtObj2;

            connObj.Close();

            SetFirstRowSelected();
        }

        private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetFirstRowSelected();
        }
    }
}
```

### Solution

---

I figured out what I needed:

```
string query2 = "SELECT SUM([Total-Length-Weight]) FROM (Select DISTINCT [Material], [Total-Length-Weight] from [Sheet1$])";
```

Thanks for the help you all.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Excel queries before but the syntax looks like T-SQL.  If that's the case, I think what you're looking for is a `group by`:

```
string query2 = "Select [material], Sum([Total-Length-Weight]) AS `Total Length Weight` From [Sheet1$] group by [material]";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `group by` here, so:

```
Select [Material], SUM([Total Length Weight])
from `table` 
group by [Material]
having [Material] <> ''
```

**EDIT**

If we care about *just one* weight per material, and we can assume that all entries are always the same, then we can cheat and use `MIN` or `MAX` eg:

```
SELECT SUM(Weight) FROM
   (Select [Material], MAX([Total Length Weight]) 'Weight'
    from `table` 
    group by [Material]
    having [Material] <> '' )
```

Comment: I tried that, but that gives me the sum of each material, which is not what I want... Each material has a value for the weight, and it is identical for that material (Every weight for `name1` = 33). Using your method if there were two `name1`s then id get 66... that's not what I want.

Comment: If you can ignore cases where the weights aren't identical, then change `SUM` to `MIN` or `MAX` then

Comment: this still works by material, not the whole table. and when I try it, I get No value given for one or more required parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix query 2 by a [GROUP BY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx).

So for query 2:

"Select   [material], Sum([Total-Length-Weight]) AS `Total Length Weight` From [Sheet1$] group by [material]";

Answer (score 0):

What everyone is ignoring is the fact that you want to only sum distinct values, the following code should do it:

```
Select [material], Sum(DISTINCT [Total-Length-Weight]) AS `Total Length Weight`
From [Sheet1$]
where [material] <> ''
group by [material]
```

Comment: This is more like what I am looking for, but I get the following error message:  Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Sum(DISTINCT [Total-Length-Weight])'.

Comment: It could be a copy/paste error, sometimes the formatting makes a single quote into a weird quote. Check where you go AS 'Total Length Weight' make sure those are single quotes and not the weird one

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but I actually figured it out. See my revised information in my main post. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried without the "where" and the "as" alias? Just to check? Because I'm pretty sure my code will work without having to resort to a derived table

Comment: So far, I have tried several permutations of the code and it always throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! :)

Here is the query I needed:

```
string query2 = "SELECT SUM([Total-Length-Weight]) FROM (Select DISTINCT [Material], [Total-Length-Weight] from [Sheet1$])";
```